# KIvy GL fatal error

Tags: python, opengl, kivy, intel, kivy-language

I'm trying to learn `kivy` to make an mobile application for my college project but when i ran this sample script on the `kivy` website its gave me error:

```
OpenGL version detected :1.1
```

do after that i did :

```
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
```

i'm getting this :

[image]

here is the terminal output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\User\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-04-23_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-e831904, 20170420
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] No framebuffers extension is supported
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'1.4.0 - Build 8.14.10.1930'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel 945GM'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 1, 4
[CRITICAL] [GL          ] Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!

OpenGL version detected: 1.4

Version: b'1.4.0 - Build 8.14.10.1930'
Vendor: b'Intel'
Renderer: b'Intel 945GM'

Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems.

The application will leave now.
```

I tried to ugrade my Graphics driver, but still this exists, i refered to other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969990/kivy-does-not-detect-opengl-2-0) [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351087/kivy-opengl-requirements-feasible-for-deployment?rq=1) but none solves the Problem.

I really need help with with because `kivy` is the only thing which can help me in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Intel 945GM only supports up to OpenGL 1.4](https://communities.intel.com/thread/24284#136739).

*So you need to use another device or graphics card.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer , can you please tell me which is the least GL version `Kivy` supports. so that i can use another machine accordingly .

Comment: Your error actually mentions that. You need to at least support OpenGL 2.0. If you support any newer version, then you usually also have backwards capability supporting older versions.